# VBA Code no longer recognizing worksheet after adding a second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up an excel spreadsheet to track when weather stations are reporting for use in Tableau to create a dashboard so we can track the communication health of the network.

This is being done through an API get that pulls the data every 10 minutes and then gets the difference between the timestamp on the data and a Now() function. If it is over 10 minutes it gets a 0 or if it is under it gets a 1 in Column H. My code is used to move those values from Column H to the right column associated with the right time period. And then on the top of the hour move what im calling the "HourScore" to the correct hour column which is then used to calculate the "DayScore" which is simply the percentage of times it accurately communicated in the entire day.

It was all working great when I only was tracking one organization; now I'm tracking two and it stopped functioning after I added a second sheet for the other utility.

I've tried a handful of different ways to get the object reference to work, but don't have a ton of experience with VBA so I'm unable to really pinpoint the exact problem.

I've also tried separating them into different workbooks but they are both constantly running on a virtual server and I kept getting errors. That code looked very similar to what is below but each If function was split up.

```
Sub Minute_Save()
' Refresh Queries
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

' Creates a variable array from the pge_minscore Column
Dim pge_ws As Worksheet
Dim pge_minscore As Range
Dim pge_hourscore As Range

Dim sge_ws As Worksheet
Dim sce_minscore As Range
Dim sce_hourscore As Range

Set pge_ws = Worksheets("PGE")
Set pge_minscore = Range([E2], [E:E].Find("*", [E1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))

Set sce_ws = Worksheets("SCE")
Set sce_minscore = Range([E2], [E:E].Find("*", [E1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))

' Copy Data Refresh into MinuteTable for MinuteScore
If Minute(Now()) < 10 Then
    pge_ws.Range([H2], [H:H].Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([H2], [H:H].Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value

ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 10 And Minute(Now()) < 20 Then
    pge_ws.Range([I2], [I:I].Find("*", [I1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([I2], [I:I].Find("*", [I1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value

ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 20 And Minute(Now()) < 30 Then
    pge_ws.Range([J2], [J:J].Find("*", [J1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([J2], [J:J].Find("*", [J1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value

ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 30 And Minute(Now()) < 40 Then
    pge_ws.Range([K2], [K:K].Find("*", [K1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([K2], [K:K].Find("*", [K1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Cells.Value = sce_minscore.Cells.Value

ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 40 And Minute(Now()) < 50 Then
    pge_ws.Range([L2], [L:L].Find("*", [L1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([L2], [L:L].Find("*", [L1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(sce_minscore.Rows.Count, sce_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = sce_minscore.Cells.Value

ElseIf Minute(Now()) >= 50 Then
    pge_ws.Range([M2], [M:M].Find("*", [AC1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    sce_ws.Range([M2], [M:M].Find("*", [M2], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(sce_minscore.Rows.Count, sce_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = sce_minscore.Cells.Value

    Set sce_hourscore = sce_ws.Range([N2], [N:N].Find("*", [N1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))
    Set pge_hourscore = pge_ws.Range([N2], [N:N].Find("*", [N1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))

        ' Copy MinuteScore to pge_hourscore
        If Hour(Now()) = 0 Then
            sce_ws.Range([O4], [O:O].Find("*", [O1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(sce_hourscore.Rows.Count, sce_hourscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = sce_hourscore.Cells.Value
            pge_ws.Range([O4], [O:O].Find("*", [O1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(sce_hourscore.Rows.Count, sce_hourscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = sce_hourscore.Cells.Value
      -some more code that is the same as above for more hours-  
       End If
    End If
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "Minute_Save"
End Sub
```

I receive:

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Following AJD's instructions I changed the above to the following code:

```
Set pge_ws = Worksheets("PGE")
Set pge_minscore = pge_ws.Range("H2:H500")

Set sce_ws = Worksheets("SCE")
Set sce_minscore = sce_ws.Range([E2], [E:E].Find("*", [E1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))

' Copy Data Refresh into MinuteTable for MinuteScore
If Minute(Now()) < 10 Then
    'pge_ws.Range([H2], [H:H].Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
    'sce_ws.Range([H2], [H:H].Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).Resize(pge_minscore.Rows.Count, pge_minscore.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = pge_minscore.Cells.Value

    Set startRange = pge_ws.Range("H2")
    Set endRange = pge_ws.Range("H:H").Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    pge_ws.Range(startRange, endRange) = pge_minscore.Cells.Value
```

This worked; but I'm not entirely sure why. I should be able to adapt what ADJ gave me to the rest of it for my purposes. I think it is because I don't really fully understand the difference between values and ranges. Obviously I know ranges are a collection of cells but wouldn't that mean that ranges are just a collection of values? Either way it is beyond the scope of this post so thanks to the folks that helped out I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Shouldn't you qualify your references? Example: `Set pge_minscore = Range(...)` should be `Set pge_minscore = pge_ws.Range(...)` You were working fine until you added another sheet, this is your clue that your references are not qualified. Your _implicit_ `ActiveSheet` works just fine with one sheet, but it's not working now.

Comment: Even with that qualified I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: I wasn't implying it was the answer to your question, which is why I left it as a comment and not an answer. But it _can lead to issues and unexpected results_ when you don't qualify, and therefore it's good programming practice to __always__ qualify your objects, preferably all the way up to the workbook, but _no less than_ the worksheet.

Comment: You should look at AJD's answer and the usage of `Option Explicit`.

Comment: The `Range` object refers to a place on a worksheet, and has a lot of properties - background color, font, content, size, address, and many others - often, but not necessarily, including value. So saying that ranges are collections of values can be a contextually accurate description... but technically they are (a lot) more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always add `Option Explicit` to the top of any module. **Always**.

In this case, it would have alerted you to the undeclared variable `sce_ws` to which you would have responded by changing `Dim sge_ws As Worksheet` tp `Dim sce_ws As Worksheet`.

In addition, the following construct may have issues - what if you do not find a result? In addition, because you are using shorthand notation (`[H2]`) are you sure that the value in the parameters is a Range and not a Value? Or perhaps the range you think it is, as these are not fully qualified, and could refer to a different sheet.

```
pge_ws.Range([H2], [H:H].Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))
```

To test this theory, try:

```
set startRange = pge_ws.Range("H2")
Set endRange = pge_ws.Range("H:H").Find("*", [H1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
pge_ws.Range(startRange, endRange).Resize ' etc
```

Comment: Apologies; that error was from me trying to figure it out and try different things. I was receiving the first error before I even dimmed any of that. When it is correctly sce_ws I'm still receiving the 1004 error for whichever sheet I'm not on. But my understanding is that is the entire point of the Worksheets object, I don't understand why that is not enough to qualify a reference.

Comment: Check my edits. But using `Option Explicit` should provide a more meaningful error message and it should highlight the line of code that is causing the [first] error.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this I really appreciate you taking the time. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've got

`Dim sge_ws As Worksheet`

But here you're trying to set this variable to worksheet:

`Set sce_ws = Worksheets("SCE")`

Hence why you are getting `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`

Comment: There is something else going on other than my typo; when it is correct I still receive the error.